# ReportViewer: Grouping / Repeating Table?

Tags: reportviewer, rdlc, reportviewer2008

I'm not quite sure how to do this. I went to the resource: http://www.gotreportviewer.com/, but I couldn't find the exact answer. I'm using VS 2010 .NET Framework 4, so I assume I'm also using ReportViewer2008. Oh, and I am using RDLC files.

They showed a table example where the data was grouped/sorted and they had Group Header and Group Footer's, which seems to be what I want (I think), but I can't figure out how to add those rows to my table.

Basically I have an Object (Registration) which contains:

- Group Name
- First Name
- Last Name

I pass in an ObservableCollection as the Object DataSource. What I want to do is this:

```
[GroupName]
 [First Name] [LastName]
Total: ##
...
Grand Total: ##
```

Basically, sort by: GroupName, then FirstName, then LastName. I think the way I need my data grouped/sorted is self-explanatory. I have the sorting down pact, but I can't filter/repeat the data. And, I'm not sure how to get Total / Grand Total. I'm sure I could figure out Grand Total, but Total... I have no idea.

Comment: Need a little more information, but it sounds like you are using .RDLC files (no SQL Server Reporting Engine like with .RDL files).  If so, do you have the report (.RDLC file) built already or are you attempting to create the report nn the fly with code?  In my experience I build the report in VS2010, set up groupings there etc...  Usually though, your Total: ## will be a group sub-total, and the Grand Total will go in the Grid's Footer.

Comment: I am using RDLC files, but I don't remember how to create the table properly so that it conforms to the way I'm trying to do it. Even doing things like clicking on the row group and "Add Total>After" doesn't give me the total, just a table row that's blank.

Answer (score 1):

I was having trouble with the Grand Total. I'm using VS2010 and finally I found out how to add a Grand Total to my report. I only have one group so I selected the little down arrow next to 'Group1' at the bottom of the screen, where it says 'Row Groups'. Then selected 'Add Total' and then selected 'After'. This added a row to the bottom with an expression like: Sum(field). I changed this to Count(field), which is what I needed, field being the field needed for the Grand Total.